# Item in Navbar shifting up when adding logo

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar

I've recently started using Twitter Bootstrap. When creating a Navbar, my login item gets shifted up, instead of centered, when I add a logo.

This is how it looks with a logo added onto the far left of the bar (you cannot see logo in picture). I want the "Log in" item to be in the middle of the black navbar. Any ideas? What it looks like is that the logo streches the bar down, leaving black space underneath, possibly another reason why my vertical divider does not reach the bottom.

Here is a pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/efFwO.png

Here is the navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container"><!-- Collapsable nav bar -->
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>

<!-- Your site name for the upper left corner of the site -->
<a class="brand"><img name="" src="logo.png"  alt=""></a>

<!-- Start of the nav bar content -->
<div class="nav-collapse"><!-- Other nav bar content -->

<!-- The drop down menu -->
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
<li class="drop down">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <strong     
class="caret"></strong></a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<!-- Login form here -->
<form action="CheckLogin.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input id="username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="username" size="30"
placeholder="Email"/>
<input id="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" 
type="password" name="password" size="30" />
<input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" 
name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
<label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

<input id = "submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width:
 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: Adding this CSS rule fixes it, but are there any other solutions?

```
.nav li
{
padding-top:5px;
}
```

Comment: What is your issue with using the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical centering is a pain -- there are ways to do it but it'll be unnecessarily complicated for your situation, so it's not recommended. It's best to give the nav a fixed height, and either move the buttons or the logo explicitly (for example using top paddings as you suggested) so that everything is centered properly.

There are other possible solutions along these lines:

1. Use a smaller version of the logo image that doesn't stretch down the navbar.
2. Use CSS to set the size of the logo image to something explicitly smaller than it is currently (height:30px;).
3. Use CSS to set the nav to a fixed height and add an overflow:hidden so that the image doesn't spill over. (height:30px; overflow: hidden;).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, appreciate it!

Comment: point #3 will not work because the image is in the brand class outside the ul with the nav class.  also if you set the height like that the collapse part (btn-navbar toggling div with nav-collapse) will expand to max the height and the nav items below that height will not be accessible.  i am facing the same issue, except i have to show this big image (36px height).  still no solution for me.  why cant people be satisfied with what is already there... why do they have to go around tweaking things that are already adequate! :)